# Define a list in class and call it and use it in a function in python

Tags: python, list, function, class, object

I am new to classes and objects in python and in need of help.
I need to create a student class with the attributes "Classes taken". This object should store the class number (like 001), the semester it was taken it (like “fall”), and the grade the student obtained.
I am stuck with `“Class taken”` attribute. I don’t understand if I have to create a list or define it some other manner.

Basically, I am unable to define a list and call it and use it in a function.

and error is

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance for help :)

```
class Student(object):

def __init__(self, number,ClassNumber,Semester,Grade):
    self.number = number
    self.classTaken=[]

def register():
  ClassNumber = input('Enter ClassNumber:  ')
  Semester = input('Enter Semester:  ')
  Grade = input('Enter Grade:  ') 
  print(self.classTaken.append(Student(Semester)))

student1= Student.register(self.classTaken)
```

Comment: There's a couple problems with the code. For example, the attribute `self.Classes` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere; register is a function, but should be a method; also, `list.append` doesn't return anything.

Comment: It would help if you explain what you're trying to achieve. For example, what should the `Student.register` call return? What is `classTaken` going to be used for?

Comment: Student.register need to collect ClassNumber, Semester, Grade and place it in an object. Classes taken is an object that should store the class number (like 001), the semester it was taken it (such as "Fall"), and the grade the student obtained.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I don't think you need a Classes taken attribute at all. So the Student.register should be a method that returns a new Student instance? the instance should have the mentioned attributes within it.

Comment: Please post the code with the actual indentation.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `def __init__(self, number,ClassNumber,Semester,Grade):`, why does `self` (correctly) appear in that list? Do you think perhaps that logic should also apply to `def register():`? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self):
        self.classTaken = []

    def register(self,Number,ClassNumber,Semester,Grade):
        self.classTaken.extend((Number,ClassNumber,Semester,Grade))

student1 = Student()
student1.register(4,2,6,8)
print(student1.classTaken)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me :)

Comment: OK No Problem :)